# Eclipse Java writes Hebrew words in reverse order

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a Java programmer at Eclipse.
When I try to write in Hebrew, the direction of the words is reversed - for example: when I want to write

```
System.out.println ("הכנס ציוני תלמידים לפי מספרם ברשימה");
```

("Enter student scores according to their number in the list")

Eclipse changes this to

```
System.out.println ("ברשימה מספרם לפי תלמידים ציוני הכנס");
```

("list the in number their to according scores student Enter")

And also printed that way. I tried changing the encoding but it did not help.
Anyone know what the problem is?
(Just points out that in order to download Eclipse I had to delete the folder C: \ Users \ *************. P2)

Comment: Can't reproduce, Hebrew displays fine in eclipse on my system. Don't know what the problem is but it's something specific to your system. Are you sure you use UTF-8 encoding? What version of java/eclipse/operating system do you use?

Comment: Since this works in IntelliJ properly, I doubt this is a Java-related problem, but rather something with your Eclipse settings. Do you have bidirectional support enabled? Check Window > Preferences > General > Globalization > Enable bidirectional support

Comment: @vs97 Maybe your suggestion will help OP, on my system it works fine with bidirectional support disabled(the default).